# javascript document.write and innerHTML output different values

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I am converting PhP data that comes in as a 24 hour time (19:13:00) and changing it to output as 7:13pm and I have a function that seems to work just fine when I do document.write(timeString), but when I do innerHTML all I am seeing is 6:00am for everything.

```
console.log(timeString) => correct
console.log(typeof timeString) => string
document.write(timeString) => correct string
document.getElementById('testingSpan').innerHTML = timeString => 6:00am ?????
```

not sure what else I could try to output the correct value into my HTML

```
var testingSpans = document.getElementsByClassName('testingSpan');
var timeinString = <?= json_encode($view_variable, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
var H = +timeinString.substr(0, 2);
var h = (H % 12) || 12;
var ampm = H < 12 ? "AM" : "PM";
timeinString = h + timeinString.substr(2, 3) + ampm;
                                            document.write(timeinString); //outputs correct string
for (var kk = 0; kk < testingSpans.length; kk++) {
    testingSpans[kk].innerHTML = timeinString; //outputs 6:00am no matter what
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up fixing my issue by using createElement() and setting the innerHTML to the timeString in my javascript function and then using appendChild() to add it to my html.